# iOS: How to keep my application running in the background forever?

Tags: ios, service, background

my application is hosting a filesharing web server. And I want that the application is running, even when it in the background. I already know that I can run my application 3 minutes in the background by setting a `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` but this is not long enough. Is there a way to keep the app running forever, or at least for a much longer time?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I finally figured out a working way, its a bit odd but it works.

I have on procedure

```
-(void)bgTask {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ApplicationURLScheme"]];
}
```

that is been called in `applicationDidEnterBackground` with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
            [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                [self bgTask];
            }];
```

Thats it, no more code needed, I am running my Webserver in the Background for over an hour now! And the app is not lagging or crashing my iDevice!

Comment: Did you check the Apple docs?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i did for my app when i need the app to run in background to scan for iBeacons forever :

```
- (void) backgroundForever {
        backgroundTaskID = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
             [self backgroundForever]; 
        }];
}

- (void) stopBackgroundTask {
       UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
       if(backgroundTaskID != -1)
            [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
}
```

So basically we start a new background task when the current background task ends. 
You call stopBackgroundTask to whenever you want to stop the background task. It's up to your application logic, Eg you can call this in applicationDidEnterForeground.

It works, but i'm not sure if your app will pass Apple review.

Comment: Ok, after 3 minutes I go into [self backgroundForever]; (I added a NSLog). The Problem is that my app is freezing after the 3 minutes. So when I open the app again it is not responding to anything. If I run the app for a long time in the background I get a blue-screen which is quite funny:)

Comment: How do you know your app is freezing ? Can you pause the execution (from XCode) and see what's happening in the main thread ?

Comment: Well I know it because I opened it and I was not able to do anything.

Comment: @namanhas I just noticed, when I launch the app after the 3 minutes the task won't stop. It is going and going. And that applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive are not called. Do you know why?

Comment: @DavidG.: i've updated my answer. Have you figured out why your app freezes ?

Comment: Still, same bug, the app freezes if i open it and if i love it in the background my iDevice crashes. In the console I get lots of clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name. I guess this is happening because The application never exits the background task. I show you my code in the question.